# Prove by induction that $\sum_{\varnothing\ne S\subseteq[n]}(\prod S)^{-1}=n$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction, power-series

I'm having a hard time visualizing how to prove the following by induction:

For every positive integer $n$, let $[n]$ denote the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

> Let $A$ be a set.  Use the notation $P(A)$ to indicate the power set of $A$, which consists of all subsets of $A$.  For example, if $A=\{0,1\}$, then $P(A)=\big\{\{\},\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\big\}$.  Consider $Q(n) = P\big(\{1,\ldots,n\}\big)-\big\{\{\}\big\}$ and use an inductive argument to show that the sum
>
> $$\sum_{S\in Q(n)}\frac1{\prod S}=n\;.$$

For example, the expansion for $n=3$ is

$$\frac11+\frac12+\frac13+\frac1{1\cdot2}+\frac1{1\cdot3}+\frac1{2\cdot3}+\frac1{1\cdot2\cdot3}=3\;.$$

Comment: I modified the statement of the question to match the example; please check to see that it’s correct. In case the notation is unfamiliar, $\prod S$ is the product of the members of the set $S$.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Thank you very much. I'm new here and haven't figured out how to inset equations yet.

Comment: You’re very welcome. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a reference and tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that it’s true for $n$:

$$\sum_{S\in Q(n)}\frac1{\prod S}=n\;.\tag{1}$$

We want to show that it’s true for $n+1$, i.e., that

$$\sum_{S\in Q(n+1)}\frac1{\prod S}=n+1\;.\tag{2}$$

Every non-empty subset of $[n]$ is a non-empty subset of $[n+1]$, so $Q(n)\subseteq Q(n+1)$. What are the other non-empty subsets of $[n+1]$? They’re exactly the subsets of $[n+1]$ that include the integer $n+1$. In other words, they’re the set $\{n+1\}$ and the sets of the form $S\cup\{n+1\}$ with $S\in Q(n)$. This means that

$$\sum_{S\in Q(n+1)}\frac1{\prod S}=\sum_{S\in Q(n)}\frac1{\prod S}+\sum_{S\in Q(n)}\frac1{(n+1)\prod S}+\frac1{n+1}\;;$$

why? Now use the induction hypothesis $(1)$ to show that $(2)$ holds.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. 

I understand the induction that 

$\sum_{S\in Q(n+1)}\frac1{\prod S}=\sum_{S\in Q(n)}\frac1{\prod S}+\sum_{S\in Q(n)}\frac1{(n+1)\prod S}+\frac1{n+1}\;$

$\sum_{S\in Q(n+1)}\frac1{\prod S}=n+\sum_{S\in Q(n)}\frac1{(n+1)\prod S}+\frac1{n+1}\;$

Although I'm still unclear how to show 

$\sum_{S\in Q(n)}\frac1{(n+1)\prod S}+\frac1{n+1}\;$ = 1

Comment: @Tommy: Does it help if I point out that $$\sum_{S\in Q(n)}\frac1{(n+1)\prod S}=\frac1{n+1}\sum_{S\in Q(n)}\frac1{\prod S}\;?$$

Comment: Yes! That was what I was missing! Thank you very much! I've been stuck on this 2 days now. It has been 7 years since I last took a discreet mathematics class, needless to say I'm more than a little rusty. I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: @Tommy: You’re very welcome!